# Execute make prerequisite every time

Tags: makefile

My makefile:

```
.PHONY: test-unit test-functional mocha

test: test-unit test-functional

test-unit: SUITE = "unit"
test-unit: mocha
    @echo "unit"

test-functional: SUITE = "functional"
test-functional: mocha
    @echo "functional"

mocha:  
    @echo ===== RUNNING TESTS: $(SUITE) =====
```

I'd like to use this makefile to run both of my test suites without duplicating the code for what it takes to run a suite (abstracted into the `mocha` task).  However, Make is being smart and realizes that `mocha` has already been run when it comes to `test-functional` and doesn't run it again.

`make test`:

```
===== RUNNING TESTS: unit =====
unit
functional
```

Is there a better way to approach this perhaps to achieve similar abstraction, or perhaps flag `mocha` as needing to be run every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Canned Recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) for the body of the `mocha` task and stick it in both test tasks.

Instead of

```
mocha:
    @echo ===== RUNNING TESTS: $(SUITE) =====

test: mocha
```

use

```
define mocha
@echo ===== RUNNING TESTS: $(SUITE) =====
endef

test:
    $(mocha)
    ....
```

`define mocha =` (or `:=` etc.) for make 4.0+ I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't prefer the canned recipe approach for my application for reasons unimportant.

To solve this for myself, the prerequisite is a .PHONY and my harness-target calls each step as a sub-make:

`dedupe-emails-1` and `dedupe-emails-2` both depend on the same target which must be re-made.

```bash
run: create-views 
    $(MAKE) dedupe-emails-1 
    $(MAKE) dedupe-emails-2 
    $(MAKE) report-dupes.csv
```