# Gnu make - Force "Remake" of prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Makefile-snippet:

```
x:
        @ echo reached $(@)
a:      x
b:      a x
```

`make b;` on commandline echoes only once: how to get `x` executed every time it is referenced (2 times in this example); in other words: how to make `make` forget that `x` has already been done as a prerequisite of `a`, so it runs as a prerequisite of `b` too ?
found [Execute make prerequisite every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259181/execute-make-prerequisite-every-time) but maybe there are other approaches.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that you can do this. Why do you want to? Are you using `x` as a pure-output "stamp"/"message"?

Comment: yes, a kind of debugging target

Comment: Then the linked canned recipe answer is likely the best solution. Though depending on what you want you might be able to use fancy `SHELL` tricks as well (e.g. redefine `SHELL` for the targets in question).

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer; i'll try what the link suggests